# Get Getter Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, setter, getter, getter-setter

In JavaScript there is the possibility to create getters and setters the following way:

```
function MyClass(){
 var MyField;
 this.__defineGetter__("MyField",function(){
  return MyField;
 });
 this.__defineSetter__("MyField",function(value){
  MyField = value;
 });
}
```

But is there a way to get the Getter or Setter FUNCTION? I think of something like this:

```
var obj = new MyClass();
obj.__getSetter__("MyField")("MyValue");
```

I need such a functionality when extending base classes. For example:
Class "A" has field "a", Class "B" extends from "A" and also wants to have a field "a".
To pass values from the "a"-field of a "B"-object to the "a"-field of a "A"-object I need to get the setter/getter function before overriding them.

Comment: I would advice against relying on that non-standard syntax.

Comment: you can add the answer as an answer and select it since you found it for yourself

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## The old way

[`__defineGetter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__) and [`__defineSetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineSetter__) have been deprecated in the time since this question was initially posted.

Accessing those accessor and mutator functions was handled with [`__lookupGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__lookupGetter__) and [`__lookupSetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__lookupSetter__) respectively.

### Example

```js
function MyClass() {
 var MyField
 this.__defineGetter__("MyField",function(){
  return MyField
 })
 this.__defineSetter__("MyField",function(value){
  MyField = value
 })
}

var obj = new MyClass()
obj.__lookupSetter__("MyField")("MyValue")
console.log(obj.MyField)
```

## The new way

The current standard way to create a dynamic accessor or mutator is to use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) or [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties).

Accessing accessor and mutator functions can be done using [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) and [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors).

### Example

```js
function MyClass() {
 let MyField
 Object.defineProperty(this, 'MyField', {
   get: () => MyField,
   set: value => {
     MyField = value
   }
 })
}

var obj = new MyClass()
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'MyField').set('MyValue')
console.log(obj.MyField)
```

## ES6 Classes

Note that `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` works even when using `get` and `set` keywords, however there are a couple gotchas if you're using the `class` keyword.

Accessors and mutators defined on a `class` are not "own properties" of the instances of that class. Instead they belong to the prototype for that class (`class` is just syntactic sugar for declaring a prototype).

Because the functions added to the class are added to the prototype you will need to be careful about context when calling the getter or setter.

```js
class MyClass {
  get MyField() {
    return this._myField
  }
  set MyField(value) {
    this._myField = value
  }
}

const obj = new MyClass()
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(MyClass.prototype, 'MyField').set.call(obj, 'MyValue')
console.log(obj.MyField)
```

Answer (score 21):

Actually, `__lookupGetter__` and `__lookupSetter__` methods are **deprecated**. Instead of these you must use:

```
/* __lookupGetter__ */
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'MyField').get;

/* __lookupSetter__ */
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'MyField').set;
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [**lookupGetter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/lookupGetter).

Answer (score 1):

In Google Chrome lookupGetter/lookupSetter is broken: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=13175