# 'Computed Property' in Vanilla Javascript Class

Tags: javascript

The *computed properties* feature is common in popular JS frameworks (React, VueJS) but how do we implement this in vanilla JS?

Let's say that given a `User` class, with a `dateOfBirth` property, we would like to compute its `age`, is there a better way to perform this task than the code below?

```
function User(name, dateOfBirth) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;

    this.age = function() {
        return now() - this.dateOfBirth;
    }
}

var driver = new User('Steve', new Date('12 December, 1990'))
driver.age()
```

In the code above, we are retrieving the `age` value by calling a method. However, is it possible to be able to retrieve the value with just `driver.age`?

Comment: There are no computed property names here. Better to put `age` on the prototype

Comment: yes you can using a `getter`

Comment: Though, the code you've presented is very incomplete

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822953/get-getter-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether it's "better" or not is a matter of style/opinion, but if you want a property rather than a method, you can create an *accessor property*, in your case an accessor with a *getter* but no *setter*.

Making minimal changes to your code, you'd do it like this:

```
function User(name, dateOfBirth) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;

    Object.defineProperty(this, "age", {
        get() {
            return now() - this.dateOfBirth;
        }
    });
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function now() { return Date.now(); }
function User(name, dateOfBirth) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;

    Object.defineProperty(this, "age", {
        get() {
            return now() - this.dateOfBirth;
        }
    });
}

var steve = new User("Steve", new Date(1990, 11, 12));
console.log(steve.age);
```

You can define those more concisely using an object initializer (note that this example throws away the object created via `new User` and returns a different one instead, which doesn't have `User.prototype` as its prototype):

```
function User(name, dateOfBirth) {
    return {
        name,
        dateOfBirth,
        get age() {
            return now() - this.dateOfBirth;
        }
    };
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function now() { return Date.now(); }
function User(name, dateOfBirth) {
    return {
        name,
        dateOfBirth,
        get age() {
            return now() - this.dateOfBirth;
        }
    };
}

var steve = new User("Steve", new Date(1990, 11, 12));
console.log(steve.age);
```

I've also used the new (ES2015+) *shorthand property syntax* there for `name` and `dateOfBirth`.

This is also compatible with ES2015's `class` syntax:

```
class User {
    constructor(name, dateOfBirth) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
    get age() {
        return now() - this.dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function now() { return Date.now(); }
class User {
    constructor(name, dateOfBirth) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
    get age() {
        return now() - this.dateOfBirth;
    }
}

var steve = new User("Steve", new Date(1990, 11, 12));
console.log(steve.age);
```

Comment: Is there an obvious advantage of the second code example where the user.prototype is not created?

Comment: @puoygae - It's *created*, it's just not used. That's also a matter of style. Personally, I don't like to use `new X` unless I'm making use of `X.prototype` (directly, or via `class` syntax). So if I were going with that second option, I'd probably call it `createUser` and call it without `new`. But I like prototypes and I like `new`, so I tend toward `class` syntax these days.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can use a `getter` to return a computed value, like so:

```js
class User {
  constructor(name, dateOfBirth) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
  }

  get age() {
    return new Date() - this.dateOfBirth;
  }
}

var driver = new User('Steve', new Date('12 December, 1990'));
console.log(driver.age);
```

More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Although this answer is correct and even uses the latest ES6 class, I have opted to choose T.J. Crowder's answer because it corresponds to the version of JS that I have used in my question.